# Google Chrome thinks my site is phishing

Tags: php, google-chrome, phishing

I built a simple PHP website.  Google says it's a phishing site.  What things could I have in my PHP code that makes Google Chrome think my website is a phishing site, and how do I fix this problem?  I collect the user's IP address to prevent multiple votes on a voting system I have.  Could this be the problem?

Comment: http://sb.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/

Comment: I did that.  I'm trying to figure out if there's something I can do to make sure it doesn't happen again.  (Or does reporting it fix it?)

Comment: Check your code for any unwanted parts. It's possible your ftp got hacked and some files were corrupted - if that happened, change the passwords

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be acting like a hacked site. A review can help you.

> http://www.google.com/webmasters/hacked/

If not, you should contact google.